# Building Array of Structures problems

Tags: c, structure

Im trying to read a file, put specific tokens into a structure and read them.

The file im reading has the following format

```
Edward is enrolled in CSE 1105.
August is enrolled in CSE 1105.
SoonWon is enrolled in MATH 1426.
```

My psuedocode to hopefully help you follow

```
Open file 
send file to function create_structures to be tokenized
read file fgets(), then tokenize strtok() by delimiter space
name/course will be 1st and 5th token, add tokens to array of structures
```

The code so far is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void create_structures(FILE* file);

struct info{
    char name[20];
    char course[4];
};

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("input-hw04b.txt","r");
    create_structures(fp);

}

voidcreate_structures(FILE* file)
{
    struct info struct_array[30]; /* Correct? want struct to be like 
                                     strcut info struct_array = {{"Edward","1105."},
                                                                 {"August","1105."}};ETC..*/
    char buffer[100];
    char* del = " ";
    char* token;
    int number,index,count;

    while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),file) != NULL)
    {
        index = 0;
        count = 0;
        token = strtok(buffer,del);
        while(token != NULL)
        {
            if(count == 0)
            {
                strcpy(struct_array[index].name,token);
            }
            if(count == 5)
            {
                strcpy(struct_array[index].course,token);
            }
            token = strtok(NULL,del);
            count = count + 1;
        }
        index = index +1;

        for (index = 0; index < count; index++)
            printf("%s %s\n", struct_array[index].name, struct_array[index].course );
    }
}
```

When i print the structure i get the following output

```
Edward 1105.

.
 �

(�n�� �
 �
�I9�� �

August 1105.

.
 �

(�n�� �
 �
�I9�� �

SoonWon 1426.

.
 �

(�n�� �
 �
�I9�� �
```

Anyone know what all those extra characters are? My friend says, "The problem is that you try to store the values from each line of the file in the same exact structure." but I didn't really understand him. That's what i'm trying to do, add it to the array of structures.

Comment: i use strtok to get name so i believe the token is NULL terminated

Answer (score 1):

You have to move

```
   for (index = 0; index < count; index++)
        printf("%s %s\n", struct_array[index].name, struct_array[index].course );
```

outside of the outer `while` loop.

Also you have to move

```
index = 0;
```

before the outer `while` loop.

Because what happens now is you try to print your N entries N times (every time you read the new line). But you always write into position 0.

UPDATE. Shouldn't the inner loop be simply:

```
while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),file) != NULL)
{
    token = strtok(buffer,del);
    strcpy(struct_array[index].name,token);
    token = strtok(buffer,del);
    strcpy(struct_array[index].course,token);
}
```

Comment: thanks, it work kind of now, apparently the course entry into the structure is now 1105.August so now i gotta figure out why its adding the name into the end of the coutrse

Comment: I think you should remove your `if count==0` and `if count==5` statements, you already know the entries structure, so just assign the first token to the name and the second to the course.

Comment: but there are several tokens, the second token would "is" since im using the delimeter as a space, thats why i count the tokens because the tokens are "edward" "is" "enrolled" "in" "CSE" "1105."

Comment: ah I see. but I don't think you need `token = strtok(NULL,del);` part at all. look at this example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Answer (score 1):

```
struct info{
    char name[20];  
    char course[4];  // make at least course[5] for null-termination
};
```

Your initial problem is you do not have sufficient room in course to hold the course number. A string requires + 1 characters to make room for the '\0' terminating character.

You have additional logic errors that are messing up your print. Look at the following for ideas of how to print each record as it is read, and also how to print all records after you have completed reading the file:

```
int number,index,count;
index = 0;

while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),file) != NULL)
{
    count = 0;
    token = strtok(buffer,del);
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        if(count == 0)
        {
            strcpy(struct_array[index].name,token);
        }
        if(count == 5)
        {
            strcpy(struct_array[index].course,token);
        }
        token = strtok(NULL,del);
        count = count + 1;
    }

    /* to print each record as read, print before "index +1" */
    printf("%s %s\n", struct_array[index].name, struct_array[index].course );

    index = index +1;

}

/* to print all records after you finish reading */
int iter = 0;
for (iter = 0; iter < index; iter++)
    printf("%s %s\n", struct_array[iter].name, struct_array[iter].course );
```

You have further problems with your delimiter. After reading course, you still have a `.` left in the buffer. You can cure that with:

```
 char  del[] = " .";
```

You can also clean up your logic and error checking a bit further with the following:

```
#include <errno.h>
...
char fname[] = "dat/courses.txt";  /* put your filename back in here */
FILE* fp = fopen(fname,"r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Couldn't open file %s; %s\n", fname, strerror (errno));
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
...
char  buffer[100];
char  del[] = " .";
char* token;
int   index,count;
index = 0;

while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),file) != NULL)
{
    count = 0;

    token = strtok(buffer,del);
    if (token != NULL) {
        strcpy(struct_array[index].name,token);
        count += 1;
    }

    while((token = strtok(NULL,del)) != NULL)
    {
        if(count == 5)
        {
            strcpy(struct_array[index].course,token);
        }

        count = count + 1;
    }

    index = index +1;

}
```

output:

```
struct_array[0]  Edward  1105
struct_array[1]  August  1105
struct_array[2]  SoonWon  1426
```

Comment: its printing correctly but i cant spot the course entry error. for course all i want it to be is something like "1105." but now its of form "1105.August" so i have another problem,any logic error you can spot real quick?

Comment: That's definitely not what you want, give me a minute and I'll take another look.

Comment: @user3686360 I have discovered the source of your `August` error, there were additional characters that remained in buffer after reading course. Changing delimiter cures the problem. Check updated answer.